# Multiple list in Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I need to create sort of multiple list in Laravel Nova, where I could write text.
Reference from other CRM::
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuHbG.png)

It's nessesary for pass this list to the page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGxxI.png)
That site admin had a comportable interface for fill these properties.

I see that in database it should be the separate table which will connect to the current table by the conditional field.

Is there, in Laravel Nova, such possibility? I didn't find the solve for my issue. Please help.

Comment: https://novapackages.com/packages/whitecube/nova-flexible-content or https://github.com/outl1ne/nova-simple-repeatable.